# Can I ignore and continue in Selenium IDE 3.17 if my script gets an error

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium IDE 3.17

If my script has an error I want it to continue rather than stop.

The error log shows "X ended with 1 error(s)"

Is there anyway it can just carry on?

I've tried using other automation software but looking to see if it's possible in Selenium IDE

**The script:**

Command: wait for element present | Target: ID:OpenButton | Value: 9999

Command: Click | Target: ID:OpenButton | Value:

Command: wait for element present | Target: ID:ReplyButton | Value:

Command: Click | Target: ID:ReplyButton | Value:

Command: wait for element present | Target: ID:CloseButton | Value: 500000

Command: Click | Target: ID:CloseButton | Value:

This is the script. The issue is if we don't find ID:OpenButton in time the script will fail. I can increase the wait but I want to create a loop where we can keep trying.

Comment: use the `storeEval` command with JavaScript code to handle errors. Can you post the code?

Comment: I've updated the post

This is the script. The issue is if we don't find ID:OpenButton in time the script will fail. I can increase the wait but I want to create a loop where we can keep trying.